# How can I use setregion() to set region when user location is moving only?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I have tried removing my setRegion() but it still persists to not allow map panning. The build overrides finger gestures for exploring the mapview and responds very briefly before reverting back to original position. I am not sure the issue. I have rewritten my code to a new project and there is no issue, can anyone explain to me where I am going wrong?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let regionInMeters: Double = 15000
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        checkLocationServices()
    }

    
    func setupLocationManager(){
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }
    
    func centerUserLocation(){
        if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate{
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func checkLocationServices(){
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
            setupLocationManager()
            checkLocationAuthorization()
        } else {
            // alert user must turn on
        }
    }
    
    func checkLocationAuthorization(){
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus(){
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            mapView.showsUserLocation = true
            centerUserLocation()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            break
        case .denied:
            mapView.showsUserLocation = false
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            break
        case .restricted:
            //supervisory controls enabled
            mapView.showsUserLocation = false
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            mapView.showsUserLocation = true
            break
        }
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else {return}
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: center, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        checkLocationAuthorization()
    }
}
```

Comment: Let’s  share a piece of your code to make more clear your question

Comment: What `userTrackingMode` have you set on the map view?

Comment: @sekoya added code

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't recall explicitly setting a trackingmode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `setRegion` in `didUpdateLocations` - This will change the map region every time you get a location update; about once per second with `best` accuracy; even when the user isn’t moving

If you want user tracking on your map view, you should use the in-built [`userTrackingMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1616208-usertrackingmode) capabilities.

Comment: I did that because i anticipate adding navigation/directions. but as it stands, if i swipe on the mapview (while built) it returns back to user location automatically at the set region altitude. are you saying i should call set region else where?

Comment: Only call `setRegion` when you want to set the map’s region. At the moment you keep setting it every time you get a location update delegate call. You need to decide under what conditions you want to recenter the map